# ActiveX checkboxes slows down opening/load time of workbook

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016, activex

I have an Excel workbook with around 150 ActiveX checkboxes. All these Active X controls leads to long load time when opening the workbook (about 20 sec on my computer). Is there any way to speed up the load time of the workbook (without changing to form controls)?

Comment: FYI: You shouldn't be relying on ActiveX it is a deprecated technology.  No longer supported in Edge.  I don't know how much longer they will allow it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Seems like changing to Form controls is the only solution. It would be interesting to know why Active X control affect the startup time while Form controls doesn't .